# Android Firebase Database Error: Permission denied when debug on a phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I believe this will be quick one. My first android app with firebase real time db. When I run the app using emulator (Android studio Pixel XL API 30 - Android 11.0) - all good and I have no issues even if my  rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

or rule for the .read is set to true. But when I run the same version on my selfphone I get the "Permission denied" exception when trying to read the data from the db.

For sign in I use GoogleSignIn by this part of code:

```
private fun signIn()
{
    var signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        var task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(
            data
        )
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>)
{
    try
    {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account)
        var intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: ApiException)
    {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("Log", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
        updateUI(null)
    }
}
```

I downloaded the google-services.json again but still the same issue. Also I added auth.addAuthStateListener to get some info about firebase authentication.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature_setup)

    initializeGoogleSignIn() // to get login context for logout
    auth = Firebase.auth
    auth.addAuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        runit(firebaseAuth) }
    initializeNavigation() // menu etc.
}

private fun runit(firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth)
{
    if (firebaseAuth.currentUser == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no way sir", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "maybe?", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

The code querying firebase realtime db is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature_setup)

    initializeGoogleSignIn() // to get login context for logout
    auth = Firebase.auth
    auth.addAuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        runit(firebaseAuth) }
    initializeNavigation() // menu etc.

    readInitialDataFromDb()
}

private fun readInitialDataFromDb()
{
    var db = Firebase.database.getReference(dbNameRooms)
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this)
}

override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
{
    if (rooms?.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        rooms = snapshot.getValue<List<Room>?>()
        createRoomLayout()
    }
    else
    {
        // anything here?
    }
}

override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled reading db", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

When I run this on the emulator - I got current user and onDataChange called. Running that on my Android 10 phone gives me null for current user and onCancelled with db access denied. Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks
R

Comment: I don't see any code that would query the database and fail as you describe.  With your rules, you will have to make sure the query happens only after the user is fully signed in.

Comment: That's what I don't understand why it's ok using emulator and not ok using phone. I'm looking for the difference between those two runs.

Comment: I'm confused.  You're saying that you don't have any code that queries the database?  If you have code, show it, and also show that the user is signed in at the time of the query.  Otherwise, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Added the code part for quering db - edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the root cause of the issue. The emulator is authenticated by default using **FirebaseDefaultUser** - that's why it passes the authentication rule. On the phone it works the way it should work so until a firebase user is authenticated the user is blocked from using firebase realtime db (assuming you have set the rules that every user needs to be authenticated to read/write).

I'm leaving this a bit opened as I didn't follow up why the default user is used there and what's the difference on the emulator.

To make the firebase auth work I needed to amend my code to use the google sign in and then use the google sign in credentials to get the authenticated firebase user.
The following code is the most useful one (from the firebase guide on [its github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/GoogleSignInActivity.kt))

```
// [START onactivityresult]
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from 
GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
// [END onactivityresult]

// [START auth_with_google]
private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressBar()
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    val view = binding.mainLayout
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Authentication Failed.", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                hideProgressBar()
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
}
// [END auth_with_google]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is querying the database before the sign-in completes.  You have to wait for a complete sign-in before security rules that require authentication will be satisfied.

Auth state listeners are asynchronous, and are only invoked when a user is fully signed in or signed out.  You should use your [addAuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) more like this:

```
    auth.addAuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
            readInitialDataFromDb()
        }
    }
```

Notice that the query is only being performed after it detects that a user is present.

Comment: That will just prevent the exception from db reading but it's not solving the issue I have. Why I have different behaviour when using the same google sign in account on both emulator and my phone and having various output? Thank you for you help but still I need to authorise the user on my phone to be able to get the data from db.The google sign in displays that the user is autheticated successfully.

Comment: I can assure you that the behavior you're seeing is not because of the device or emulator.  "Permission denied" errors are always about the lack of permission granted by security rules.  Since your rules only require a signed in user, that is the one way the results of the query can be considered denied.  You really do want to write your code to avoid the error - that's a requirement of the security rules system.

Comment: Hi Doug, I got your point but even if I change the code you propose the issue is still there for my phone but not for the emulator so the question is still there. I think I lack the info about linking googleSingIn with Firebase.auth. I have the common googleSignIn for firebase (from the tutorial) but I miss the use of the googleSignIn for firebase.auth probably.